# Где теперь раздел "знаки"?

Tags: поддержка

На сайте ‘English language and usage’ он есть, а у нас на него никак не удаётся выйти.

Comment: Кто-нибудь ответит мне? Хотя бы можно ли на этот раздел как-то выйти и, если нет, может ли это измениться в будущем.

Answer (score 1):

Артем, прошу прощения, что не заметил ваш вопрос. Вы говорите об этой странице: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/badges?

Comment: Ничего страшного, Aer, спасибо, что теперь ответили. Да, я именно об этой говорю.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой я, кстати, помню о вашем вопросе про разделитель разрядов, но, увы, администрация сайта молчит...

Comment: Спасибо большое, что помните! Жалко, но ладно.) Теперь я понял, как страницу знаков открывать, и за это спасибо! ;)